# React-Grid-layout shake a bit onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-grid-layout

I'm working with React-grid-layout in React.js.
When I click on the draggable tile, it shakes a bit, and same happens when I click on any child button on the tile.
**How can I stop this shaky behaviour?**

[image]

Here, `Set Alarm` is a button, when I click on it, the respective tile shakes (moves a bit down and back on its position).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had added margin on each tile that was somehow making the tiles shake. After removing the margin from css class, the issue resolved.

**Note, React-grid-layout gives a special `margin` attribute to add margin between tiles.**

Hope this answer help someone in future!
Good day.